# Dealing with strange characters in org babel results

Tags: org-babel

I am playing with SaltStack configured by org babel source blocks.
I try to pass output of salt fingerprint to minion configuration file.
If I use one command direcly in bash I receive this output:

```
# salt-key -f master.pub
Local Keys:
master.pub:  66:bf:a3:8f:f5:09:01:78:dc:d7:34:80:42:d0:ab:b6:f1:f6:67:ee:dd:80:10:d6:90:58:71:48:fa:d9:24:2c
```

When I try to execute the same command in org babel I receive different result (I attach screen because my browser doesn't support this symbol):

```
#+begin_src sh :session master
salt-key --finger=master.pub
#+end_src
```

[image: org babel result]

Because of this ^[ characters I receive wrong while extracting value of master.pub key which I need in further processing:

```
#+begin_src sh :session minion :var FINGERPRINT=fingerprint[1,1]
echo $FINGERPRINT
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
|                                                                                                    |
| 66:bf:a3:8f:f5:09:01:78:dc:d7:34:80:42:d0:ab:b6:f1:f6:67:ee:dd:80:10:d6:90:58:71:48:fa:d9:24:2c;0m |
```

And because of the ";0m" at the end (I am not sure what it is) I can't copy and paste this value to configuration file.
I tried different types of results (raw, table, list), but always I receive this characters. Anyone have idea how can I deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are terminal escape codes to e.g. change colors and such. Usually, programs that do that have a --color=no or some similar option to turn this off. In fact,
the [salt-key manpage](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/cli/salt-key.html) shows a `--no-color` option, so try adding that to the `salt-key` invocation.

Comment: Thank you! Now the output is fine!